# Why would you want an integer overflow to occur?

Tags: c#, .net, overflow, integer-overflow

In this question the topic is how to make VS check for an arithmetic overflow in C# and throw an Exception: [C# Overflow not Working? How to enable Overflow Checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878548/c-overflow-not-working)

One of the comments stated something weird and got upvoted much, I hope you can help me out here:

> You can also use the checked keyword to wrap a statement or a set of statements so that they are explicitly checked for arithmetic overflow. Setting the project-wide property is a little risky because oftentimes overflow is a fairly reasonable expectation.

I dont know much about hardware but am aware that overflow has to do with the way registers work. I always thought overflow causes undefined behaviour and should be prevented where possible. (in 'normal' projects, not writing malicious code)

Why would you ever **expect** an overflow to happen and why wouldn't you always prevent it if you have the possibility? (by setting the corresponding compiler option)

Comment: (reference) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Your statement "overflow causes undefined behaviour" is not correct... it is very well defined, especially in the case of integers.  Your statement "I don't know much about hardware" is telling in this case... you should read up a bit about binary and how addition works at the machine level

Comment: The statement probably comes from C/C++ mindset, overflow is an "undefined behaviour" which means the compiler writer can do things you don't expect when optimising.  It doesn't really matter that the CPU does have a well defined behaviour, compiler writer with the bignum constant expression evaluating optimiser, may detect it and eliminate the code "it's not a C/C++ program so I can break it".  I guess, noone needs to care in C#, because by time new hardware does things differently, MS have moved onto some new silver bullet

Comment: Overflow is very well defined behaviour in C and C++ for unsigned integers, but indeed undefined behaviour for signed integers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The main time when I *want* overflow is computing hash codes. There, the actual numeric magnitude of the result doesn't matter at all - it's effectively just a bit pattern which I happen to be manipulating with arithmetic operations.

We have checked arithmetic turned on project-wide for [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) - I'd rather throw an exception than return incorrect data. I suspect that it's pretty rare for overflows to be desirable... I'll admit I *usually* leave the default to unchecked arithmetic, just because it's the default. There's the speed penalty as well, of course...

Comment: Your precision and speed are truly annoying. Congrats!

Answer (score 10):

> I always thought overflow causes
>   undefined behaviour and should be
>   prevented where possible.

You may also be confused about the difference between buffer overflow (overrun) and numeric overflow.

Buffer overflow is when data is written past the end of an unmanaged array.  It can cause undefined behavior, doing things like overwriting the return address on the stack with user-entered data.  Buffer overflow is difficult to do in managed code.

Numeric overflow, however, is well defined.  For example, if you have an 8-bit register, it can only store 2^8 values (0 to 255 if unsigned).  So if you add 100+200, you would not get 300, but 300 modulo 256, which is 44.  The story is a little more complicated using signed types; the bit pattern is incremented in a similar manner, but they are interpreted as [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), so adding two positive numbers can give a negative number.

Comment: +1 for that great explanation. I knew the difference between the buffer and arithmetic overflow, but still thought it was (at least in theory) undefined behaviour in all cases.

Comment: Do you know by whom the overflow is well defined? Is it the hardware? Is it the platform (.NET, Java etc.)? Imagine you want to write integer hashcodes (constructed ignoring overflows) both from a .NET program on a 32 Bit machine and from a Java program on a 64 Bit machine. Assuming all integers are of the same size, are the hashcodes meaningful comparable?

Comment: @Marco - In most cases, integer overflow will be well-defined at every level, actually.  For example, [C#](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_14.7.4_Addition_operator): "any significant high-order bits outside the range of the result type are discarded", [Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html): "If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format".

Comment: @Marco - Hash codes from C# and Java would be meaningfully comparable if you know that the calculation steps were all the same.  I would only rely on it if you wrote the actual code to calculate them in both cases.  You would get the same result from adding two integers in both Java and C# if you use integers of the same size and sign-type.

Answer (score 9):

When doing calculations with constantly incrementing counters.  A classic example is Environment.TickCount:

```
int start = Environment.TickCount;
DoSomething();
int end = Environment.TickCount;
int executionTime = end - start;
```

If that were checked, the program has odds to bomb 27 days after Windows was booted.  When TickCount ticks beyond int.MaxValue while DoSomething was running.  PerformanceCounter is another example.

These types of calculations produce an accurate result, even though overflow is present.  A secondary example is the kind of math you do to generate a representative bit pattern, you're not really interested in an accurate result, just a reproducible one.  Examples of those are checksums, hashes and random numbers.

Comment: In that case an exception is quite possibly better than underflow - often aborting is better than producing incorrect data which may then cascade through the system. Depends on the situation, of course.

Comment: unless it overflows more than once.  :)

Comment: @darron - this is relevant for a time measurement of *one* millisecond.  The 'overflow more than once' angle is 27 days.  Or 54, depending.

Answer (score 6):

**Angles**

Integers that overflow are elegant tools for measuring angles. You have 0 == 0 degrees, 0xFFFFFFFF == 359.999.... degrees. Its very convenient, because as 32 bit integers you can add/subtract angles (350 degrees plus 20 degrees ends up overflowing wrapping back around to 10 degrees). Also you can decide to treat the 32 bit integer as signed (-180 to 180 degrees) and unsigned (0 to 360). 0xFFFFFFF equates to -179.999..., which equates to 359.999..., which is equivelent. Very elegent.

Answer (score 3):

> why wouldn't you always prevent it if you have the possibility?

The reason checked arithmetic is not enabled by default is that checked arithmetic is slower than unchecked arithmetic. If performance isn't an issue for you it would probably make sense to enable checked arithmetic as an overflow occurring is usually an error.

Comment: Ok, I didnt know that and it sounds reasonable. That still doesn't explain why the comment states that "oftentimes overflow is a fairly reasonable expectation"? Looking at how often it got upvoted (+10 in 2 hours) he doesnt seem to be the only one with this opinion?

Comment: The difference is mainly in signed arithmetic. Because of the way 2's complement numbers work, the 8-bit 11111111 is actually negative 1 instead of the sByte.MinValue -128 (as you might have expected). It makes sense though; adding 1 to -1 should result in zero, so adding 00000001 to 11111111 == 00000000. That's technically arithmetic overflow; the carry bit of 1 off the left end of the byte doesn't have anywhere to go in the allocated byte, and so is lost. However, integral numbers go between positive and negative all the time, so this should only be an error when you want it to be.

Answer (score 3):

When generating HashCodes, say from a string of characters.

Answer (score 3):

This probably has as much to do with history as with any technical reasons. Integer overflow has very often been used to good effect by algorithms that rely on the behaviour (hashing algorithms in particular).

Also, most CPUs are designed to allow overflow, but set a carry bit in the process, which makes it easier to implement addition over longer-than-natural word-sizes. To implement checked operations in this context would mean adding code to raise an exception if the carry flag is set. Not a huge imposition, but one that the compiler writers probably didn't want to foist upon people without choice.

The alternative would be to check by default, but offer an unchecked option. Why this isn't so probably also goes back to history.

Answer (score 2):

You might expect it on something that is measured for deltas.  Some networking equipment keeps counter sizes small and you can poll for a value, say bytes transferred.  If the value gets too big it just overflows back to zero.  It still gives you something useful if you're measuring it frequently (bytes/minute, bytes/hour), and as the counters are usually cleared when a connection drops it doesn't matter they are not entirely accurate.

As Justin mentioned buffer overflows are a different kettle of fish.  This is where you write past the end of an array into memory that you shouldn't.  In numeric overflow, the same amount of memory is used.  In buffer overflow you use memory you didn't allocate.  Buffer overflow is prevented automatically in some languages.

Answer (score 1):

There is one classic story about a programmer who took advantage of overflow in the design of a program:

[The Story of Mel](http://www.retrologic.com/jargon/story-of-mel.html)

Comment: How is this a helpful answer?

Comment: While an amusing story (possibly a programmer urban legend) no one should be doing anything like that these days unless you're working at the firmware or something super low level.  Most definitely not in C#

Comment: Should be a comment, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much related to how registers work as it is just the limits of the memory in variables that store data. (You can overflow a variable in memory without overflowing any registers.)

But to answer your question, consider the simplest type of checksum. It's simply the sum of all the data being checked. If the checksum overflows, that's okay and the part that didn't overflow is still meaningful.

Other reasons might include that you just want your program to keep running even though a inconsequential variable may have overflowed.

Comment: CPUs don't do any work on memory, they do work on registers. The register is copied out to memory once it's done being worked on. So it really is about how registers overflow.

Comment: Where on Earth did you get your information from about CPUs never working directly with memory? Where is the register overflow in a statement like `ADD MyVar,1` or even `ADD [esi],1`? CPUs most definitely work directly on memory.

Answer (score 0):

One more possible situation which I could imaging is a random number generation algorythm - we don't case about overflow in that case, because all we want is a random number.

Answer (score 0):

An integer overflow goes like this.

You have an 8 bit integer 1111 1111, now add 1 to it. 0000 0000, the leading 1 gets truncated since it would be in the 9th position.

Now say you have a signed integer, the leading bit means it's negative. So now you have 0111 1111. Add 1 to it and you have 1000 0000, which is -128. In this case, adding 1 to 127 made it switch to negative.

I'm very sure overflows behave in a well determined manner, but I'm not sure about underflows.

Answer (score 0):

All integer arithmetic (well adds subtracts and multiplies at least) is exact. It is just the interpretation of the resulting bits that you need to be careful of. In the 2's complement system, you get the correct result modulo 2 to the number of bits. The only difference between signed, and unsigned is that for signed numbers the most significant bit is treated as a sign bit. Its up to the programmer to determine what is appropriate. Obviously for some computations you want to know about an overflow and take appropriate action if one is detected. Personally I've never needed the overflow detection. I use a linear congruential random number generator that relies on it, i.e. 64*64bit unsigned integer multiplication, I only care about the lowest 64bits, I get the modulo operation for free because of the truncation.